# Need DIV show/hide Switch to happen AFTER SlideToggle occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, animation

I have a series of "product" divs in a grid, each of which is clickable. When one is clicked, the corresponding "product info" DIV slides down to reveal the corresponding product info. I have it working somewhat but I'm having a couple of issues.

How can I make it so that when one set of info is showing, but ANOTHER "product" div is clicked, the current info slides into hidden status, the product info is switched and THEN the new info is revealed. Make sense?

If the code below doesn't make sense, the direct link is [here](http://gp3designs.com/starter/nancy/work.html)

This is the HTML for the hidden info. The class 'selected_show' is styled with "display:none;" to start:

```
<section>
        <div class=selected_show>
            <div>
                <div class="product_info grassone piece_info">
                    <img src="./images/detail_info/astronomical.jpg">
                    <div>
                        <p>Short description of the piece...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="product_info competitive piece_info">
                    <img src="./images/detail_info/astronomical.jpg">
                    <div style="background:red;">
                        <p>Short description of the piece...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="product_info magpie piece_info">
                    <img src="./images/detail_info/astronomical.jpg">
                    <div style="background:blue;">
                        <p>Short description of the piece...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

This is where the info is chosen:

```
<section>
        <div class="piece woodcut">
        <a href="grassone" class="showinfo"><p>GRASSONE</p></a>
        </div>

        <div class="piece woodcut">
        <a href="competitive" class="showinfo"><p>COMPETITIVE</p></a>
        </div>

        <div class="piece woodcut">
        <a href="magpie" class="showinfo"><p>MAGPIE</p></a>
        </div>

</section>
```

This is the script for the effect:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('a.showinfo').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 100 }, "slow");        
        $(".selected_show").slideToggle();

    var a_href = '.'+ $(this).attr('href');
        $('.product_info').hide();
        $(a_href).show();
    });

    </script>
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `slideToggle`'s callback:

```
$(".selected_show").slideToggle(1000, function(){
    $('.product_info').hide();
});
```